# How to merge duplicate dicts in list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have below list:

```
lst = [
       {'name': 'bezel', 'conf': 0.67},
       {'name': 'plate', 'conf': 0.69},
       {'name': 'bezel', 'conf': 0.65},
       {'name': 'plate', 'conf': 0.46},
       {'name': 'bezel', 'conf': 0.42}
]
```

Above list contains duplicate dicts which has `name` as `bezel` and `plate`. There can be `n` number of names in the list. I want to remove these duplicate dicts and only keep the dict which has high `conf`. So the output would look like below:

```
lst = [
       {'name': 'bezel', 'conf': 0.67},
       {'name': 'plate', 'conf': 0.69}
]
```

I can use multiple for and if loops to get the output, but is there any easier way of doing this?

Below is what I have done so far:

```
newLst = []  # creating new list to save data
for item in lst:
    if any(d['name'] == item['name'] for d in newLst):  # Checking if current item exist in newLst
        idx = next((index for (index, d) in enumerate(newLst) if d["name"] == item['name']), None)  # Get the index of current item name from newLst
        if newLst[idx]['conf'] < item['conf']:  # Check if its greater conf
            del newLst[idx]
            newLst.append({'name': item['name'], 'conf': item['conf']})
    else:
        newLst.append({'name': item['name'], 'conf': item['conf']})   # If not add current item

print(newLst)
```

Comment: Why did you write "merge" in the title? You're just picking one, not merging anything, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
result=[]
for n in {d['name'] for d in lst}:
    sl=[e for e in lst if e['name']==n]
    result.append(max(sl, key=lambda x:x['conf']))

>>> result
[{'name': 'plate', 'conf': 0.69}, {'name': 'bezel', 'conf': 0.67}]
```

1. `{d['name'] for d in lst}` creates a set of all possible `'name'` keys contained in the list;
2. `sl=[e for e in lst if e['name']==n]` filters for that name;
3. `max(sl, key=lambda x:x['conf'])` find the max of that filter list keyed by the `'conf'` key.

Profit!

---

If preserving order is important, use a `dict` rather than a set to uniquify the list:

```
result=[]
for n in {d['name']:None for d in lst}:
    sl=[e for e in lst if e['name']==n]
    result.append(max(sl, key=lambda x:x['conf']))

>>> result
[{'name': 'bezel', 'conf': 0.67}, {'name': 'plate', 'conf': 0.69}]
```

---

There is also the sort / uniquify method:

```
>>> list({d['name']:d for d in sorted(lst, key=lambda d: (d['name'], d['conf']))}.values())
[{'name': 'bezel', 'conf': 0.67}, {'name': 'plate', 'conf': 0.69}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a compact answer by creating a dictionary where each key is one of the possible names, if the name is not in the dict, add it with its conf, else update the maximum if needed.

```
def filter_on_key(lst):
    tmp = {}
    for d in lst:
    if tmp.get(d['name']) is None:
        tmp[d['name']] = d['conf']
    else:
        if d['conf'] > tmp[d['name']]:
            tmp[d['name']] = d['conf']
    return tmp
```

Gets you:

```
out = filter_on_key(lst)
{'bezel': 0.67, 'plate': 0.69}
```

If you want to get back the original format, a comprehension works fine:

```
res = [{'name':k, 'conf':v} for k, v in out.items()]
[{'name': 'bezel', 'conf': 0.67}, {'name': 'plate', 'conf': 0.69}]
```

Comment: I've never seen anyone use `dict.get(x) is None` before. It'd be clearer to do `x in dict`, wouldn't it?

Comment: That `else` isn't needed; you can do `elif` instead. But actually, you could make it even shorter by combining the two conditions: `if d['name'] not in tmp or d['conf'] > tmp[d['name']]: tmp[d['name']] = d['conf']`

Comment: Oops, I meant `x not in dict`

Comment: If that makes it clearer to you, sure!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict to store input dicts by name. Then you just need to remove and replace them when their `'conf'` value is higher.

```
accumulator = {}
for d in lst:
    key = d['name']
    if key not in accumulator:
        accumulator[key] = d
    elif d['conf'] > accumulator[key]['conf']:
        del accumulator[key]
        accumulator[key] = d
result = list(accumulator.values())
```

Result:

```
[{'name': 'bezel', 'conf': 0.67}, {'name': 'plate', 'conf': 0.69}]
```

Note that this is stable, i.e. the output preserves the order of the input.